# Java - how do I check if a string exists in each of the elements of a HashSet

Tags: java, collections, hashset

```
    final HashSet<String> VALUES = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.01)",
            "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.02)",
            "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.03)",
            "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.04)"}));
    String s="OK";
    System.out.println(VALUES.contains(s));
```

Gives me false. 
How do I check if "OK" exists in each of the elements?

Comment: Loop the Set and check if the String in the Set contains "OK".

Comment: I'am afraid you have to loop ...

Comment: Tangential note, you don't need the `new String[] {` or the closing `}`. Just `Arrays.asList("OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.01)", ... )`. `asList` takes a varargs `String...`.

Comment: you need to check every entry in this map by a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can test this code:

```
final HashSet<String> VALUES = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.01)",
                "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.02)",
                "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.03)",
                "no (0.07, 0.05, 0.04)"}));
        String s="OK";

        @Test 
        public void teste(){

            for (String a : VALUES) {
                if(a.contains(s)){
                    System.out.println("Ok yes!" + true);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Don't exist!" + false);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 9):

Currently, you're checking if your `Set` contains the value `OK`. If you want to check if each of the elements of the `Set` contains `OK` (note the difference), you'll need to loop through the values of your `Set` like the others stated.

Using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and [streams](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), you can also do :

```
boolean b = VALUES.stream().allMatch(s -> s.contains("OK"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You should loop on the *set* and check for every string in it:

```
for(String st : VALUES) {
    if(!st.contains(s)) { 
       //found string that doesn't contain s
    }
}
```

Note that now we are using [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean contains = true;
String s = "OK";

for (String str : VALUES) {
    if (!str.conatins(s)) {
        contains = false;
        break;
    }
}

// If contains is true here, every string in the list contains s, otherwise not.
```

Comment: You can break the loop, in your if statement, no need to check the other values, you already found one that did'nt satisfied the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method like `contains` below to loop over the elements in the `Collection`.

```
public static boolean contains(java.util.Collection<String> coll, String s) {
    for (String t : coll) {
        if (t == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!t.contains(s)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final HashSet<String> VALUES = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.01)",
            "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.02)",
            "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.03)",
            "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.04)"}));
    System.out.println(contains(VALUES, "OK"));
}
```

Which outputs `true` here.

Comment: Didn't he want contains? You are using startsWith.